# How to download an older version of anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I need to download an older version of AnyLogic 8.7.7 to test a model on that version, however all links, that I found didnt work for me. I use a community version, so if anyone has a link, please provide it here.

I need a clone of this link:
[www.anylogic.com/files/anylogic-professional-8.7.7.x86_64.exe](http://www.anylogic.com/files/anylogic-professional-8.7.7.x86_64.exe)
but I need a community version instead.

Answer (score 2):

This link works fine here: `https://www.anylogic.com/files/anylogic-professional-8.7.7.x86_64.exe`

As you know, simply replace the version numbers from the active version on their website

Comment: Yeah, but I need a community version, I inserted this link by mistake

Comment: Reach out to support@anyLogic.com as this one only is distributed via filling a form.

Comment: (and its called the PLE version :) )